# Get the count of element which are not display none

Tags: jquery, loops, count

i have a table with tr, a lot of them are 'display: none'
What I want achieve is to get a number of tables, which are visible.
My code below:

```
jQuery(‘.single-address’).each(function() {
 var countInputs, countInputsSelected;

 if (jQuery(this).css(‘display’) !== ‘none’) {
   countInputs = jQuery(this).find(“input[type=‘checkbox’]
[checked=‘checked’]“);
   return countInputsSelected = countInputs.length;
 }
});

   itemsAddedToList = jQuery(“.items-added-to-list”);
   itemsAddedToList.addClass(“visible”);
   itemsAddedToList.find(“span”).text(countInputsSelected);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] along with a more specific problem statement regarding the code shown

Comment: You should also use `'` and `"` isntead of `‘` and `“`

Comment: jQuery(this).css(‘display’) => jQuery(this).attr(‘display’) == true or use visible

Answer (score 0):

Use the Visible selector of JQuery on your targeted section :

> jQuery( ":visible" )

Here is the documentation https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Though cannot suggest any specific solution as mentioned in comment, for exact answer please post a minimal working code.